# Why is wxMaxima not integrating the following input, and merely polishing the input as a result instead?

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

When I input:

```
integrate((sqrt(x+sqrt(x+1))),x);
```

It results in:

```
integrate(sqrt(sqrt(x+1)+x),x)
```

The result is displayed in a more organized manner. However, it does not give me the integral. Why?

Answer (score 3):

Because it doesn't know how to solve it. You can use [`changevar`](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_19.html) to help maxima solve it. For example:

```
 exp: sqrt(sqrt(x+1)+x)$
 assume(u>0)$
 changevar('integrate(exp,x), sqrt(x+1)-u,u,x)$
 ev(%,nouns);
```

[image: integration result]

and substitute back for x:

```
 ratsubst(sqrt(x+1),u,%)
```

[image: integration result for x]